# Triggering Worksheet Macro on click of worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I've written the following macro: where cell e3 is populated using a formula and can change value. However, for this macro to work I have to press the enter key in e3 to trigger it. I wish to trigger this macro when I click on the tab it is in called "unit specification" and believe I need a second macro to trigger it. I've tried a macro (at the bottom called second macro) but this didn't work.

Can anyone help please.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
If UCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "DWW" Then
    Rows("6:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "DWW" is entered in E3, rows 
are visible
Else
    Rows("6:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "DWW" is  
entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
End If
End If


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
If UCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "THETIS" Then
    Rows("48:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "Thetis" is entered in E3, 
rows are visible
Else
    Rows("48:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "Thetis" 
is  entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
    Rows("71:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "DWW" is entered in E3, rows 
are visible
Else
    Rows("71:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "THETIS" 
is  entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
End If
End If
   End Sub

 'second macro
 private sub SecondMacro()
 call Worksheet_change
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Worksheet_Activate method. This'll run whenever the tab is selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call runYourThing 'When the cell change event is triggered, only run your thing if the changed range includes cell E3
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call runYourThing 'When the worksheet activate event is triggered, always run your thing
End Sub

Sub runYourThing() 'Run the thing
    If UCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "DWW" Then
        Rows("6:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "DWW" is entered in E3, rows are Visible
    Else
        Rows("6:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "DWW" is entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
    End If

    If UCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "THETIS" Then
        Rows("48:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "Thetis" is entered in E3, rows are visible
    Else
        Rows("48:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "Thetis" is  entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
    End If

    If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
        Rows("71:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'if "DWW" is entered in E3, rows are Visible
    Else
        Rows("71:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'if anything other than "THETIS" is  entered in E3 or E3 is blank, the rows are hidden
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: quick thing, this is kinda what i thought from the other comment but i've included my initial code where the name is at the end, i get error saying "compile error: argument not optional"... what am i doing wrong? (im not that great with macros so apologise if this is obvious) 
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Well, worksheet_change takes the range that changed as an argument. You could fix it by writing "Call Worksheet_Change(Range("E3"))". That's a bit of a hack though. Really, what you want to do is have a third sub that both the Worksheet_Activate and Worksheet_Change methods call. Worksheet_Change should only call it after you make sure the 'changed' range is equal to the cell you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, more complicated than i thought... how would i go about this?? because all the options i can think of i've already tried in a 2 macro type format - which ofc hasn't worked :(

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I mean. It's pretty simple stuff, just reorganizing your code. Another note is that proper formatting/indenting will help you enormously when trying to figure out what a block of code actually does.

Comment: Brill many thanks works perfectly!! didn't quite appreciate it was that easy - i was almost there which is a win in my books!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are 3 different events you can use here

1. `Worksheet_Activate()`
   runs if the worksheet is activated (if you switch from another sheet to this sheet).
2. `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
   runs if a value in a cell changes.
3. `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
   runs if you select another cell

So you can decide which is the event that fits you most.

Comment: so i've used #2 for my macro i wish to trigger. and want to have a second macro which triggers my first macro which looks at the cell value in e3. However, this value can change based on prior criteria (populated using formula). So i want my second macro to say something like #1 then trigger initial macro but i cant get the trigger to work :(

Comment: @PGD15 Very unclear. Edit your original question and be much more specific please.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read your macro, it appears that you want certain rows to automatically hide based on changes to the cell value of `E3`. If that's right, then I think the following replacement to your code would work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then checkE3
End Sub

Sub checkE3()
    Dim E3val As String
    E3val = UCase$(Range("E3").Value)
    Rows("6:47").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (E3val = "DWW")
    Rows("48:70").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (E3val = "THETIS")
    Rows("71:75").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (E3val = "")
End Sub
```

This would 'fire' if the value of E3 changes due to the user altering it themselves **but not** if there is a formula in E3 which when re-calculated, causes the change.

In this case, you might want to run `checkE3` on other events, such as a `Worksheet_Calculate()`. This would cause it to be run far more often than you need, basically every time the a recalculate is performed, but the resource used in checkE3 is very small so you'd unlikely see any problems unless there's a **lot** of calculation going on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    checkE3
End Sub
```