# Trigger a worksheet macro when user enables macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trigger a macro in an Excel Worksheet whenever its Excel Workbook is opened and macros first run, similar to the macro `Workbook_Open` except within one of the Worksheets in that Workbook. Incidentally (though I assume it's not important to this question) what I want to do is to automatically set an Image object's Visible attribute to False as soon as macros are enabled, so that the image (which says something like "Please enable macros") will disappear.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202246/trigger-my-macro-code-when-user-enables-macros-in-excel) which answers how I could do it for a Workbook, but that doesn't work for me because the Workbook doesn't know about the Image in the Worksheet.

I found [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818748/triggering-worksheet-macro-on-click-of-worksheet) which answers how I could use `Worksheet_Activate` to do it when the user clicks away from my Worksheet and then clicks back to it, but that doesn't work for me because I want it to run immediately upon opening the Workbook, even before the user clicks on that Worksheet. (It seems kind of dumb that my message would remain visible even after the user had enabled macros, and doesn't actually stop requesting that they enable macros until they click away from the Worksheet and then click back to it.)

How can I make something like to a `Worksheet_Open` macro that runs in a Worksheet as soon as macros are enabled? Or alternatively, how would I call a user-defined method in my Worksheet from the `Workbook_Open` macro? I found how I can get a reference to that worksheet from within my Workbook...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
   Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   ...?
End Sub
```

...but I can't figure out how to call my user-defined macro in my "Sheet1" Worksheet.

Comment: If you use the worksheet's *codename* then you can call like (eg) `Sheet1.MyMacro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 different methods:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '#1 - use the worksheet's codename
    Sheet1.MyMacro
    
    '#2 - declare worksheet variable as specific worksheet "subclass"...
    '     Just a long-winded version of #1
    Dim ws As Sheet1 'using sheet codename
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.MyMacro
    
    '#3 - declare as generic Object
    Dim ws2 As Object
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'using tab name
    ws2.MyMacro                                 'late-bound call
    
    '#4 - using CallByName
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet 'as worksheet OK here...
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    CallByName ws3, "MyMacro", VbMethod
End Sub
```

For #2 and #3, you can't declare `ws As Worksheet` because the "out of the box" `Worksheet` object doesn't have a method `MyMacro` and so you'll get a compile-time error - by declaring as the more generic `Object` you can delay that check until run-time, where it can pass...